# Moving an object back and forth with touch

Tags: ios, swift

I need to move an object side to side on the screen with the users touch. I have already made the object move with the users touch but I want to make it so the object or image can only be moved right or left. What code should I use to do this? Here is what I have right now.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Person: UIImageView!
    var location = CGPoint (x: 0, y: 0)

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch : UITouch! = touches.first! as UITouch

        location = touch!.locationInView(self.view)

        Person.center = location

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch : UITouch! = touches.first! as UITouch

        location = touch!.locationInView(self.view)

        Person.center = location
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    Person.center = CGPointMake(160, 330)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You can change the y to change how you want the UIImageView to always stay on but make sure both are same! At the least, this should give you an idea or put you in the right direction.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Person: UIImageView!

    var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch : UITouch! = touches.first! as UITouch

        location = touch!.locationInView(self.view)

        let point = location.x

        Person.center = CGPoint(x: point, y: 160) // change 160 to set vertical height you desire

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch : UITouch! = touches.first! as UITouch

        location = touch!.locationInView(self.view)

        let point = location.x

        Person.center = CGPoint(x: point, y: 160) // change 160 to set vertical height you desire
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Person.center = CGPointMake(160, 330)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I am sure there are better ways but I am still a beginner so...